# Create new tab config in admin magento2 error sorting?

Tags: magento2

I had created new module in magento2, When I create new tab get error:

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in
>   ...\vendor\magento\module-config\Model\Config\Structure\Mapper\Sorting.php
>   on line 34

This code in system.xml file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Magento Addons Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2015 Magento Addons (https://www.magentoaddons.com)
 * @package Custom_Base
 */ 
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="new_module" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
            <label>New module</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="base" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Base Configuration</label>
            <tab>new_module</tab>
            <resource>Custom_Base::config_module</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Base</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Base</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you remove var folder?

Comment: Code is working perfectly. For double check please remove system.xml and check again still error is showing or not?

Comment: i follow code of @manthandave, it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is extra space before `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. Otherwise your code works for me.

Try after removing space.

Below Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * @author Magento Addons Team
     * @copyright Copyright (c) 2015 Magento Addons (https://www.magentoaddons.com)
     * @package Custom_Base
     */ 
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
        <system>
            <tab id="new_module" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
                <label>New module</label>
            </tab>
            <section id="base" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Base Configuration</label>
                <tab>new_module</tab>
                <resource>Custom_Base::config_module</resource>
                <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Base</label>
                    <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Enable Base</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </section>
        </system>
    </config>
```

- Please Delete  **VAR/GENERATION** directory
- Clear the cache and  also **remove cache** folder from **VAR** directory
- Run **cache:clean** and **cache:flush** Command and then try

Comment: Happy to help keep helping :)